# Update repo version when building in docker before deploy

Tags: git, docker, github

I am trying to update my repo/apps version while building and deploying in docker ...
So i have this code in my `.DockerFile`

```
RUN node ./bump-version.mjs
RUN yarn run build
```

And this is the content of the `bump-version` file :

```
import { promisify } from 'util';
import { exec } from 'child_process';

const execAsync = promisify(exec);

async function execute(command) {
  console.log(`EXECUTING : ${command}`);
  const { stdout, stderr } = await execAsync(command);
  if (stdout?.length) console.log(stdout);
  if (stderr?.length) console.error(stderr);
}

await execute('git config --global user.email "system@MY_DOMAIN" ');
await execute('git config --global user.name "System"');
await execute('git remote set-url origin https://MY_TOKEN@git.MY_DOMAIN/front/room/App.git');
await execute(`yarn version --patch`);
await execute(`git push origin master --tags`);
```

And I got this error :

```
267Error: Command failed: git push origin master --tags
268error: src refspec master does not match any
269error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.MY_DOMAIN/front/room/App.git'
```

NOTE1: The `master` branch does exist
NOTE2:  The code works if I run it from my local dev environment
NOTE3: I tried to add a commit before pushing but there was another error

```
259EXECUTING : git add package.json
260EXECUTING : git commit -m "published version 1.2.3"

272 cmd: 'git commit -m "published version 1.2.3"',
273 stdout: 'HEAD detached from ac8cd529\\nnothing to commit, working tree clean\\n',
```

NOTE4: The code is on private gitlab host and the docker is run throw cicd pipeline

OR, Is there any way to run husky git hooks on gitlab ? `post-commit` or `post-merge`

Comment: Running this in a Dockerfile, as part of creating a reusable image, seems like an unusual place to put it.  Can you run this script on the host system instead?  (I might not expect your image to contain the `.git` directory or a `git` binary.)

Comment: Well I need the version to be changed before building it ! any idea ?  any other solution ? @DavidMaze